# Div's doesnt align in IE8

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I have been trying to get two div's next to each other. But it doesn't seem to work on IE 8, even though everything looks good on Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m and Firefox 30.0

All i need is a master div with two div's next to each other and **spread through the entire screen**. I don't need any spaces empty to the left or right.

At the moment, they are next to each other but the percentage of width doesn't seem to hold good. IE 8 needs div ifrm to be 100%, but then chrome and Firefox will just place it below div leftsidebar. When ifrm is 84%, Chrome and Firefox look happy, but IE 8 leaves some place next to it.

I am adding the code here below. Please provide your valuable comments.

Thanks

Below is the html:

```
<div id="mainmasterdiv" class="pageXpress">
    <div id="leftsidebar">
</div>

    <div class="ifrm">
        <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" name="iframe" src="homepage.do" style="height: 524px;">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS goes here.

```
.pageXpress {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
div#leftsidebar {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 5px;
    min-height: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 15%;
}
.ifrm {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#iframe {
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 84%;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot for firefox/chrome?

Comment: doesnt let me add images, since i am a new member to this forum

Comment: Use a file uploading website like tinypic

Comment: Here it goes [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2f0esu0/8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with the styling but the contents within the iframe seemed to shrink, probably because of the fixed width contents.

Have fixed them all looks fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested on IE, but i corrected some properties you can see all the code [at codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEGDK) : you don't need to add `display:block` if your element is floating. * I don't need any spaces empty to the left or right.* so i removed left margin on leftsidebar and add float right on iframe. I've reseted also default margin on body, and make html and body 100% wide. Is it what you want ?
P.S. You can add `overflow:hidden` on master div to reset float.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the iframe rather than ifrm

Comment: i thinked so too, try display:block on it. I tried in IE8 on windows 7 and it's ook, perharps you're in compatibility mode http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1196-internet-explorer-compatibility-view-turn-off.html ?